# Curve in union of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

If a smooth curve $\gamma: [0,T] \to \mathbb R^n$ is contained in the union of hyperplanes
$$ \bigcup_{i=1, \dots, N} H_i$$
does it then follow that one can always find time intervals $[t_0, t_1]$ sufficiently small, so that $\gamma(t)$ is contained in one of the hyperplanes, say $H_{i*}$ ?

Comment: You want to find, for any point in the domain, such an interval containing it in its interior?

Comment: Then  no. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I am sorry. I didnt want to say that "for any point $t$", but only for one point. So here is again what I wanted to say. **I want to know if there is a point $t$ and an open set $O_t$ around this point so that the curve is solely contained in one hyperplane $H_{i*}$.**

Comment: **Please** edit the question so that it asks the actual question you wanted to ask.

Comment: the main question actually asks this. I deleted my comment, which was false!

Comment: Well, your deleted comment, which you added when I asked for clarification, clarified the question into something else! :-)

Comment: yes, that was my bad, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct a $C^\infty$ function $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f$ vanishes in each interval of the form $[1/3^n,2/3^n]$ or $[-2/3^n,-1/3^n]$with $n\in\mathbb N$ and nowhere else.

Use it to construct a smooth curve in $(-1,1)\to\mathbb R^3$ with image contained in the union of the $xy$- and $xz$-planes such that no open set containing $0$ is mapped into one of those planes.

Hint: use the function $f$ so that your curves spends the time in the intervals of the form $[2/3^{n+1},1/3^n]$ with $n$ odd in one of the planes and those with $n$ even in the other plane.

Comment: Ok. This does not answer the question as amended by on of the comments...

Answer (score 0):

If there is a $t$ such that $\sigma(t)$ is in exactly one of the hyperplanes, then clearly a small neighborhood of that $t$ works: this is immediate, by continuity. Indeed, the complement of the union of the other hyperplanes is an open set of $\mathbb R^n$, so its preimage by $\sigma$ is an open set of $\mathbb R$ which contains the point $t$.

If there is no $t$ with that property, then the curve lives in the finite union of lower dimensional affine subspaces which you can get by intersecting the hyperplanes, and you can proceed inductively.